# Update the HTML input field value from <li> list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page. I am creating `<li>` elements dynamically there. Basically it is coming from an Autocomplete API. It has an input box, whenever you start typing something, it suggests the `Website logo`, `website name` and `website URL` in the `<li>` elements. It is done till now. But, whenever you click on any `<li>` element, I want to update the input field value with website name. That means, suppose once you click on "Linkedin" from the list, the input field value should be updated to "Linkedin". Because, I want to do a POST request with this value later. I am appending the list dynamically here, `$(".results").append('<li data-value="01"><img src="'+item.logo+'">'+item.name+item.domain+'</li>');`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#suggest").autocomplete({

    minLength: 0,
    delay: 100,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $(".ui-autocomplete").remove();
      // Suggest URL
      var suggestURL = "https://autocomplete.clearbit.com/v1/companies/suggest?query=%QUERY";
      suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

      // JSON Request
      $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
          url: suggestURL
        })
        .success(function(data) {
          response(data);
          $(".results > li").remove();
          data.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(item.name, item.logo, item.domain);

            $(".results").append('<li data-value="01"><img src="' + item.logo + '">' + item.name + item.domain + '</li>');


          });

        });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}


/* * Copyright (c) 2012 Thibaut Courouble
     * Licensed under the MIT License
       ================================================== */

body {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  color: #404040;
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #1e7ad3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.container,
.main {
  width: 640px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 50px
}

input {
  font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #555860;
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.search input {
  height: 26px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 12px 0 25px;
  background: white url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/5/5JuDgOa.png") 8px 6px no-repeat;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #a8acbc #babdcc #c0c3d2;
  border-radius: 13px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px #e5e7ed, 0 1px 0 #fcfcfc;
}

.search input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #66b1ee;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(85, 168, 236, 0.9);
}

.search input:focus+.results {
  display: block
}

.search .results {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #cbcfe2 #c8cee7 #c4c7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fdfdfd), color-stop(100%, #eceef4));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fdfdfd, #eceef4);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search .results li {
  display: block
}

.search .results li:first-child {
  margin-top: -1px
}

.search .results li:first-child:before,
.search .results li:first-child:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border: 5px outset transparent;
}

.search .results li:first-child:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #c4c7d7;
  top: -11px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:after {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fdfdfd;
  top: -10px;
}

.search .results li:first-child:hover:before,
.search .results li:first-child:hover:after {
  display: none
}

.search .results li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px
}

.search .results a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -1px;
  padding: 6px 40px 6px 10px;
  color: #808394;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.search .results a span {
  font-weight: 200
}

.search .results a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 10px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  background: url("http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/7/7BNkBjd.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.search .results a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-color: #2380dd #2179d5 #1a60aa;
  background-color: #338cdf;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #59aaf4), color-stop(100%, #338cdf));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #59aaf4, #338cdf);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

 :-moz-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #a7aabc;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.lt-ie9 .search input {
  line-height: 26px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="main">
  <form class="search" method="post" action="index.html">

    <input autocomplete="false" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." id="suggest" value="" />
    <ul class="results">

    </ul>

  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make things a bit more organized, add the item.domain to the `<li>` tag as a data attribute.

Then add a jQuery click event.

Take note, because the data is being appended to your list dynamically, attach the click event to the `document` and add the selector as shown below. Here's the example:

```js
var item = {};

item.domain = 'stackoverflow.com';
item.logo = 'image-url';
item.name = 'stackoverflow';

var x = '<ul><li data-value="01" data-domain="'+item.domain+'"><img src="'+item.logo+'">'+item.name+' '+item.domain+'</li></ul>';

jQuery('.results').html(x);

jQuery(document).on('click', 'li[data-domain]', function(evt){

  var obj = jQuery(this);

  jQuery("#suggest").val(obj.attr('data-domain'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="suggest" type="text" value="" />

<div class='results'></div>
```